# Launguages in Discrete Mathematical Structures II

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

For the grammar $G$ specified, draw a derivation tree for each of the given strings or
conclude that the string is not derivable from $v_0$.

$G = (V, S, v_0 , \rightarrow ), \\
V = \{v_o, v_1, x, y, z\}, \\
S = \{x, y, z\}$

$v_0 \rightarrow xv_0 \\
v_0 \rightarrow yv_1 \\
v_1 \rightarrow yv_1 \\
v_1 \rightarrow z$

1. The string $x^2y^2z$
2. The string $xy^2$

Comment: I have tried to format your question in a way that's actually readable. Please check to see if it's still what you meant. For the strings, $2$ is not a symbol in your alphabet $S$, so none of the strings can be derived from $v_0$. I assume you mean something else by $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to get rid of the initial symbol $v_0$, you *must* at some point apply the production $v_0\to yv_1$, at which point you have the non-terminal symbol $v_1$ in your string. In order to get rid of $v_1$, you *must* at some point apply $v_1\to z$. Thus, every derivable terminal string contains the symbol $z$, and it follows that $xy^2$ is not derivable.

In fact it’s not hard to see exactly which strings are derivable. To begin a derivation we can apply $v_0\to xv_0$ any number $n\ge 0$ of times, but eventually we must apply $v_0\to yv_1$ in order to get rid of $v_0$; at that point we have $x^nyv_1$. We can now apply $v_1\to yv_1$ any number $m\ge 0$ of times, but eventually we must apply $v_1\to z$. At that point we’re done, and we have $x^nyy^mz$, or simply $x^ny^{m+1}z$, where $m$ and $n$ are any non-negative integers. Clearly $x^2y^2z$ is in this language, with $n=2$ and $m=1$. That should tell you exactly how to derive $x^2y^2z$, and once you have the derivation, converting it to tree form is straightforward. The first step of the derivation is evidently $v_0\Rightarrow xv_0$, so your derivation tree will begin like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&&v_0\\
&\diagup&&\diagdown\\
x&&&&v_0
\end{array}$$